# Google play - refund users app purchase

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

Is there a way how to refund a user who (lets say) recommends an app to 3 more users who buy & download the app? (And user still can use the app after the purchase)

Both manual and API-based model are an option.

I understand that in Merchant account there is a way how to refund in-app purchases but does merchant account has the same option for app purchases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can refund regular purchases.  On the Finance page there is a link at the bottom for "Google Payments Merchant Console" where you can see each individual purchase and refund it.

Comment: Thank you! Will user still be able to use the app afterwards? Will I be able to link the user to the payment?

Comment: Also, is there some time limit? - Can I refund an user after (lets say) 30 days? 2 years?

Comment: The user can give you the purchase id and you can use that to find it and issue the refund.  The user will not be able to download the app again.  The user may still be able to use it if you aren't using the licensing API to check to see if it's a valid purchase.

Comment: I don't know if there is a time limit for refunds.  That might be documented officially somewhere.